# Execute an open default editor command inside vim

Tags: linux, git, bash, vim

I am trying to make a habit of never leaving my gvim, not even for executing commands in the terminal. This works fine with `:!<command>`. However if this command wants to open default editor (vim) it ironically does not work from gvim (it works from command line vim). Example:

```
:!git commit
error: Terminal is dumb, but EDITOR unset
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I can run:

```
:!git commit -m "message"
```

But I like the vim window when I am inspecting files and write commit messages. Is it possible to make the commit window appear in gvim as with command line vim?

Comment: Have you set the `EDITOR` environment variable (using `export`) in the shell that you started vim with? When you run an external command with vim, it invokes a new shell, which will inherit environment variables but not regular variables. For example, in my `~/.bash_profile` I have `export SVN_EDITOR=vim`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to shelling out using `:!` command, you may want to try Tim Pope's [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin. Quote from documentation:

> I'm not going to lie to you; fugitive.vim may very well be the best
>   Git wrapper of all time.

Once installed you can simply run the `:Gcommit` command and the commit buffer will be opened up.

Over at Drew Neil's [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) he a series on using Fugitive that is worth a look:

- [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/) - overview of series
- [Fugitive.vim - a complement to command line git](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim---a-complement-to-command-line-git/) - specific screencast using `:Gcommit`

Answer (score 1):

Git commit checks for the environment value `$EDITOR` in order to decide which editor it should to open to type the commit messages unless the messages has been specified using the `-m` optin on the commandline.

Use:

```
:!EDITOR=vim git commit
```

This will set the `$EDITOR` environment var to vim.

---

Further explanation:

(from man git-commit)

> The editor used to edit the commit log message will be chosen from the
>          GIT_EDITOR environment variable, the core.editor configuration
>          variable, the VISUAL environment variable, or the EDITOR environment
>          variable (in that order). See git-var(1) for details.

This means beside from setting environment values you can use `git config` to specify the editor. (I would do so)

```
git config core.editor vim
```

If you once done so than git commit will not check the `$EDITOR` env var anymore.

Comment: I did not think of setting the variable inside gvim, but vim prints a lot of strange characters when I commit using git from gvim after setting editor to vim. ?[28;1H~ etc...

Comment: press `Ctrl+l` to get rid of those characters